# Change Base Class Property Setter Behavior

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

So I have a base class, which has a property `ItemList`:

```
public class BaseClass {
    private List<Item> itemList;
    public List<Item> ItemList {
        set { 
            itemList = value; 
            LoadItems(); 
        }
    }
    public void LoadItems() { ... }
}
```

And now I have a derived class, in which I want to change the behavior of the function `LoadItems()`. So I did this:

```
public class DerivedClass {
    public new void LoadItems() { ... }
}
```

But when I set the property `ItemList`, only the base `LoadItems()` is called. Is there anyway I can call the new `LoadItems()` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
public class BaseClass {
    // ....
    public virtual void LoadItems() { ... }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public override void LoadItems() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make your property `virtual` and mark derived class implementation with `override`, not `new`: [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

```
public virtual List<Item> ItemList {
    set { 
        itemList = value; 
        LoadItems(); 
    }
}
```

```
public override List<Item> ItemList {
    set {
        // do something

        // you can also call base.ItemList
        // to get base class property implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Great link! It should work, though override LoadItem seems simpler. Thanks for pointing out the differences between override and new though

Answer (score 2):

Make `LoadItems()` virtual and override it in your derived class:

```
public class Base
{
   public virtual void LoadItems() { ... }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   public override void LoadItems() { ... }
}
```